# How to delete the places.sqlite of firefox and start from new

Tags: firefox

I would like to have a brand new `places.sqlite`.

But even after delete the file (and all the files and folder that i was thinking was reletad at), with firefox closed, when i restart i have all the previous entry. :-(.
I surely missed one.
I use firefox-esr version  115.8.0esr.
I would like to clarify something, cause i have a bug with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78116946/how-to-really-get-the-last-url-from-firefox-using-places-sqlite?noredirect=1#)

How would i do ?